# jQuery touchable (for mobile) disables the click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I use jQuery touchable for mobile use, so the user can hover a star rating. It works okay, but the click functionality is disabled for some reason.

Do you know what causes this? Or how to fix it?

My code:

```
t2=$('.star').Hoverable();  

    $t2.newHover2(function(e, touch){ //hoverIN
        $(this).addClass("star-rating-hover");
    }, function(e, touch){//hoverOut
        $(this).removeClass("star-rating-hover");
    });
```

Plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Touchable

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `touchable.js`, change `self.isCurrentlyTouching` to `true`.